# a, b, c instead of serial number 1, 2, 3 in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server Table like below:

```
   S.No            ID          Name
  -------        -----        -------
    1              100         Yuvraj
    2              101         Brian
    3              102         Paul
    4              103         Andrew
    5              104         Wasim
    6              105         Zaheer
    7              106         Shaun
    8              107         Lance
```

Instead of the S.No 1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on
I want English Alphabets such as S.No a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i and so on...
How to achieve this?

Comment: @JohnP: It would not have more than 26 records. Suppose if it has, then once again it should start with a,b,c....

Comment: I guess you'd have to do it programmatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use a normal tinyint column with a CHECK constraint to keep it between 1 and 26.
- Add computed column with CHAR(96 + tinyint value)

The same can be done with ROW_NUMBER() to ensure contiguous numbers in a SELECT, for example.

And modulo (`% 26`) might come in useful at some point too

However, if you have no more than 26 values in your table why not just do it manually...

Comment: In the Front End, I want to display in alphabets. In my selection I used Case but it looks very long.

Comment: @thevan: So, this is something your client can do. If you want it in SQL, then adapt some of the techniques I've offered above.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CHAR(97 + s_no) 'as_char' ...
```